# How to solve this problem raven matrices problem?

Tags: linear-transformations, recreational-mathematics, puzzle, transformation

[image: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parable_of_the_Lost_Sheep]

I am doing this free test in http://test.mensa.no/

That, as far as I know, the only problem I can't solve.

Basically we shift the first row to the right. From first to second is easy transformation. We just turn the left and right side of the shape outward.

But then from the $2$nd row to $3$rd, I have no idea what the transformation should be.

What should it be?

Comment: I'm not sure if this has anything to do with matrices, at least in the proper sense of the word in mathematics.

Comment: @MattiP. It doesn't. It's "Raven's Matrices" which is not math-related. In fact, this question is probably not considered on-topic.

Comment: Transformation? Mirroring? What? Not Math?

Comment: Perhaps from 2nd to 3rd row one operation happens to one side of the figure. Only the last figure is possible with one operation on one half of the figure above it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution is the picture in the first row last shape.

As you see from first to second row you split the image in the middle and as you put it "turn it outwards" I would say mirroring it around its vertical middle axis. And from second to third row you take the right half of the picture mirror it again first by the vertical middle axis and then the horizontal middle axis.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Not that easy fella. +1 for effort. But you're wrong. Your transformation would work for the 2nd column but not on the first.

Comment: Hmm. I still hold my argument. :)

Comment: So we only "work" on the right side? In the first column the left side is the one that switch

Comment: Hmm. that is true, thank you for pointing it out. Let me rethink this and edit the answer

Comment: You don't think my comment above did the job?